# Rails 5: error passing time_ago_in_words from controller to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to prevent users from deleting comments that are more than X minutes old. (This is determined by a status field.) I anticipate that the value of X may change in future so it's currently defined in an initializer:

```
AGE = 1.minute
```

What's the best way to pass the error message from the Comment controller to the (Server-generated Javascript Response) view?

```
if @comment.status == "locked"
  render "comments/too-old", locals: {message: "You can't delete this comment now as it's more than #{time_ago_in_words(AGE.ago)} old."}
end
```

This currently fails as we're not allowed to use **time_ago_in_words** in a controller:

> undefined method `time_ago_in_words'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `time_ago_in_words` is from `ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper` helper which will be automatically included in views.

If you need to access this method from controller then, you need to include this helper in the controller.

Assuming the controller name is **CommentsController** and action name as **destroy**:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    ...
    if @comment.status == "locked"
      render "comments/too-old", locals: {message: "You can't delete this comment now as it's more than #{time_ago_in_words(AGE.ago)} old."}
    end
    ...
  end   
end
```

Comment: This is nowhere documented. As this method is available in a module, we can include wherever needed.

Comment: I'm not sure you're following my gist. The Rails documentation is not rigorous enough. How on earth is one supposed to learn this stuff?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Rails, this is pure ruby stuff, so... someone who knows ruby, will know that way of including ruby module methods in a ruby class.